# WebMethod Files Upload

Tags: c#, asmx, webmethod

I need to create method to upload multiple files.
Here is my backend model that is passed as an `public void ImageUpload(IEnumerable<ImageModel> images)`

```
public class ImageModel
{
    public int EntityId { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string AltText { get; set; }
    public byte[] Content { get; set; }
    public int ImageRoomId { get; set; }
}
```

From the js I send formdata and is looks like this

[image]

But i get `System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.`

I can't understand where is the mistake. Do I need to use any other content type?

**UPDATE**

```
[WebMethod]
public string developmentimageupload(ImageModel[] file)
{
    return "Ok";
}
```

JS:

```
var formData = new FormData();
var formFields = container.querySelectorAll('input[type=text], select');

for(i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++){
    formData.set('File[' + i + '].Content', fileList[i]);
    formData.set('File[' + i + '].FileName', fileList[i].name);
}

for(var i = 0; i < formFields.length; i++){
    formData.set(formFields[i].name, formFields[i].value);
}

$.ajax({
    url: window.siteAdminProperties.Feeds.DevelopmentBulkImagesUploadUrl,
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function (data) {
        $('.js-images-uploader').hide();
        $('.js-images-uploaded').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you share the code of the backend method that actually handles the request?

Comment: and also provide the js code

Comment: @YoniV have updated the question

Comment: Does `Content` have a value in the webmethod?

Comment: @SeanT if i remove parameters from the method everything works fine, and I can see bot Files and FormData. Otherwise it can't even get inside the method. I cuts out on the model binding step.

Comment: @StNickolas you can use FileReader class in javascript to convert the files to base64. Then change your content datatype to a string array. I'm a bit busy to post an answer at the moment but there are plenty of examples on this site

Comment: @SeanT Im not sure that this is what causes the exception. I think that I need to find out how to name the formdata correctly so model binder can do the job

Comment: Just noticed you have a capital `F` for your client side file object and lowercase as the webmethod param?

Comment: @SeanT yes, if I set method in camel case,it says that wrong method signature

Comment: So you've changed `ImageModel[] file` to `ImageModel[] File` and it didn't work? Try setting your content type as `multipart/form-data`

Comment: @SeanT tried both, didn't work(

Comment: Do you have to send the files as binary? what about `HttpPostedFileBase` or `Base64`?

Comment: @SeanT no the point is to upload multiple files with additional data. HtmlPostedFile is okay. Anyway currently I have implemented manual mapping from request to my model as a temporary solution. Still looking for correct model-binding solution

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, just make HtmlPostedFile a list and that will handle multiple